# Find Google Meet specific startTime to take attendance

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to use "Google Apps Script Quickstart" to take attendance on Meet. This works well, but it does not identify the specific range for the startTime or endTime of a Meet, so I added the startTime.
With much support from stackoverflow users, the code developed allows teachers and other education staff to take attendance for a meet session within a specific time frame for a specific set of Meet codes.
Chrome extensions require adding things to your computer, demanding time to administer the data that is obtained, and can only be accessed for the purpose of taking attendance during the actual session.

```
        var emailAddress = sheet[i+1][1]
        var optionalArgs = {
        startTime: formatStartDate(),
        event_name: "call_ended",
        filters: "identifier==" + emailAddress + ",meeting_code==" + meetCode
        };
        function formatStartDate(){
        let date = new Date();
        const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
        let offsetDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset*60*1000));
        return offsetDate.toISOString();
        }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The full "Google Apps Script Quickstart" code plus the data above looks like this:

```
   function onOpen() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Asistencia')
      .addItem("Cursos", 'importCourses')
      .addItem('Asistencia', 'checkAll')
      .addToUi();
   } 

   function importCourses() {
    var optionalArgs = {
    teacherId: 'me',
    pageSize: 5
    };
    var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
    var courses = response.courses;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var courseName = courses[i].name;
    var courseId = courses[i].id;
    insertCourse(courseName, courseId)
     }
   }

   function insertCourse(courseName, courseId) {
    var spreadsheetName = courseName + "(" + courseId + ")"
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetName);

     if (yourNewSheet != null) {
        return
     }
     yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
     yourNewSheet.setName(spreadsheetName);
     yourNewSheet.appendRow(['Nombre', 'Email', 'Asistencia'])
     yourNewSheet.setFrozenRows(1)
     var studentNames = getRoster(courseId)["studentNames"]
     var studentEmails = getRoster(courseId)["studentEmails"]
     for (var i = 0; i < studentNames.length; i++) {
       yourNewSheet.appendRow([studentNames[i],studentEmails[i]])
     }
     yourNewSheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 2)
     yourNewSheet.setFrozenColumns(2)
   }

   function getRoster(courseId) {
        var studentNames = []
     var studentEmails = []
     var optionalArgs = {
       pageSize: 100
    };
    var response = Classroom.Courses.Students.list(courseId, optionalArgs)
    var students = response.students

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      try {
       studentNames.push(students[i].profile.name.fullName)
       studentEmails.push(students[i].profile.emailAddress)
     } catch (err) {
        return { "studentNames":studentNames, "studentEmails":studentEmails }
      }
     }
    }

   function checkAll() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var sheet = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i = 2; i < sheet.length * 100; i++){
       var meetCode = getCleanCode(sheet[0][i])

       if (meetCode == null) {
         break;
       }
       else {
         checkMeet(meetCode, i+1);
       }
     }
   }

   function checkMeet(meetCode, index) {
     var userKey = 'all';
     var applicationName = 'meet';
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var sheet = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
     var DateValue = ss.getRange(1, 1).getValues();

     for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length-1; i++) {
       var emailAddress = sheet[i+1][1]
       var optionalArgs = {
       startTime: formatStartDate(),
       event_name: "call_ended",
       filters: "identifier==" + emailAddress + ",meeting_code==" + meetCode
       };
       try {
         var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, 
    optionalArgs);
         var activities = response.items;
         if (activities == undefined) {
          markAbsent(ss,i+2,index)
          }
         else {
           markPresent(ss,i+2,index)
         }
         } catch (err) {
           continue
       }

     }
   }

   function getCleanCode(meetCode) {
     try{
      return meetCode.replace(/-/g, "");
     } catch (err) { return meetCode; }
   }

   function markAbsent(sheet, i, j) {
       var cell = sheet.getRange(i, j);
       cell.setValue("A");
   }

   function markPresent(sheet, i, j) {
       var cell = sheet.getRange(i, j);
        cell.setValue("");
   }

   function formatStartDate(){
     let date = new Date();
     const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();  
     let offsetDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset*145*1000));
     return offsetDate.toISOString();
   }
```